# stop adb logcat from running

Tags: java, android, adb

I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f log.txt -c");` In my android application.

The problem with is is that it keeps running and never stops.

Is there a command to stop the code/adb command from executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f log.txt -c"); // Deletes log.txt
proc.destroy();//kill the process
```

You can use `proc.destroy();` in `onClick()` if you want to destroy the `logcat` when click the button or `Handler` if you want to destroy it in several seconds or `onDestroy()` if you want to destroy it when the app destroyed and so on.

Comment: If I use the code like that, immediatly destroy the process, it doesn't execute the process.

Comment: use proc.destroy in onclick for example